# remove all access control in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

By default, I believe that there is a access control or access manager behind wordpress, is there a way to remove all? Since I added different roles and I want to be able to control each and every role per user level.

Comment: I don't understand this question.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this: [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/screenshots/).

It allows you to customize every admin section/action in wordpress, based on permissions levels

Answer (score 1):

Check my code, for reference:

It makes 3 differences: Admin (and userid = 1), admin (with less options), and no admin with many less options ;)

```
<?php



    add_action('wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'customize_admin_bar');

    function customize_admin_bar() {
        global $wp_admin_bar;
        if (is_user_logged_in()) {
            if ( (!current_user_can('administrator') or wp_get_current_user()->ID>1)) {
              $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('edit-profile');
              //$wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('user-info');    
              $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('wp-logo');
              $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('comments');
              $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('new-media');
              $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('new-tvr_booking');
              $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('new-vp_orbitslides'); 
              $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('orbitslider_settings');
              $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('orbitslider_settings');
              //$wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('site-name');
              //$wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('dashboard');
              /*$wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
                'id' => 'custom-account',
                'parent' => 'my-account',
                'title' => __( 'Mi cuenta'),
                'href' => '/pedidos/products-page/your-account/'
                ) );*/
            }

        }
    }
    /* TONIWEB BEGINS*/
    function wpc_dashboard_widgets() {
        global $wp_meta_boxes;
        // Today widget
        //unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_right_now']);
        // Last comments
        if (is_user_logged_in() && (!current_user_can('administrator') or wp_get_current_user()->ID>1)) {
            unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_recent_comments']);
            // Incoming links
            unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_incoming_links']);
            // Plugins
            unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_plugins']);

            unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['ts_dashboard']);
            unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_quick_press']); 
            unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_primary']);
            unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_secondary']);
            unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_right_now']);
        }
    }
    function remove_menus () {
    global $menu;
        if (is_user_logged_in() && (!current_user_can('administrator') or wp_get_current_user()->ID>1)) {
            $restricted = array(__('Dashboard'), __('Links'), __('Media'), __('Appearance'), __('Tools'), __('Settings'), __('Comments'), __('Plugins'),__('Slides'),__('Posts'),__('Profile'),__('Pages'),__('Users'));
            end ($menu);
            while (prev($menu)){
                $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
                if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted)){unset($menu[key($menu)]);}
            }


        }
    }
    function remove_add_new(){
        if (is_user_logged_in() && (!current_user_can('administrator'))) {
            if('tvr_booking' == get_post_type()){
                 echo '<style type="text/css">

                        .add-new-h2{display:none;}
                        #menu-posts-tvr_booking .wp-submenu-wrap {
                          display: none;
                        }
                        .subsubsub .all, .subsubsub .publish, .subsubsub .trash {
                          display: none;
                        }
                        </style>';
            }
            if('tvr_apartment' == get_post_type()){
                 echo '<style type="text/css">
                        .subsubsub .all, .subsubsub .publish, .subsubsub .trash {
                          display: none;
                        }
                        </style>';
            }
            echo '<style>#normal-sortables .versions,#normal-sortables .table_discussion {
                        visibility: hidden;
                }</style>';
        }
    }
    add_action('admin_head','remove_add_new');
    add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'wpc_dashboard_widgets');
    add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menus');
    add_action('admin_head', 'remove_menus');
    ?>
```